# System of Differential equations with fundamental matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the system

${dx\over dt}=2x+3y-13$

${dy\over dt} = -x-2y+9$

Using the method of undetermined coefficients and I'm totally unsure where to begin. I took the eigenvectors but from there I'm lost. Anything helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Please write down where you got to, so we know where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

differentiating your first equation with respect to $t$ we get
$$x''=2x'+3y'$$
from the first equation we have
$$y=\frac{x'-2x+13}{3}$$ thus we get for $y'$:
$$y'=-x-\frac{2}{3}\left(x'-2x+13\right)+9$$
and we get finally
$$x''=2x'+3\left(-x-\frac{2}{3}\left(x'-2x+13\right)+9\right)$$
can you finish?