# Initial value problem for systems of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks for me to solve the following initial value problem

$X'= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -24 & -26\\
1 & 2 & -3\\
1 & 1 & -2
\end{array} \right)X$

The matrix also has the initial condition $X(0)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
13\\
12\\
-13 
\end{array} \right)$.

I am unsure of what method to use and how to start.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547745/system-of-differential-equations-with-fundamental-matrix

Comment: Or diagonalize the matrix using eigen values.